# Model override not working

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

We try to override two functions from the Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item model class but unfortunately nothing happens. Maybe we missed something?

```
#File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml
<blocks>
    <models>
        <cataloginventory>
            <rewrite>
                <stock_item>Namespace_Module_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
            </rewrite>
        </cataloginventory>
    </models>
</blocks>

#File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Stock/Item.php
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{   

    public function getMinSaleQty()
    {
        echo 'test';
        exit;
    }

    public function getQtyIncrements()
    {
        echo 'test';
        exit;       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the xml appears to be wrong, blocks and models should be separate and should be included as part of the `global` node. If you update your config as below:

```
#File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml
<global>
    <models>
        <cataloginventory>
            <rewrite>
                <stock_item>Namespace_Module_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
            </rewrite>
        </cataloginventory>
    </models>
</global>
```

You should also extend the rewritten class and not the abstract so your class should start

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item
```

Answer (score 3):

File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    . . . 
    <global>
       <models>
          <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
          </module>
          <cataloginventory>
                <rewrite>
                    <stock_item>Namespace_Module_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
                </rewrite>
            </cataloginventory>
       </models>
    . . . 
    </global>
    . . . 
 </config>
```

File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Stock/Item.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item
{

    public function getMinSaleQty()
    {
        echo 'test';
        exit;
    }

    public function getQtyIncrements()
    {
        echo 'test';
        exit;       
    }
}
```